# connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, linux, nginx

On my vagrant box , centtos 7, i had installed php7.0.3 and nginx 1.9.12. the php config www.conf. this file in the /usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.d/ directory, Its configuration like this

```
user = www
group = www
;listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
```

and the nginx config.  the file vm.demo.com.conf in the /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/ directory. Its configuration like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name vm.demo.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root  /data/wwwroot/demo;

    location / {
        if (-f $request_filename/index.html){
            rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
        }
        if (-f $request_filename/index.php){
            rewrite (.*) $1/index.php;
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename){
            rewrite (.*) /index.php;
        }
    }
    location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$ {
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    access_log  logs/demo.log main;
}
```

in the nginx conf, if i use fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000 and the php-fpm.conf listen 127.0.0.1:9000, They are working properly
bug if i use the socket configuration:

php www.conf

```
user = www
group = www
listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
```

nginx vm.demo.com.conf

```
    location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

the nginx show 502 Bad gateway.  in the nginx error.log show this.

```
2016/03/14 21:17:04 [crit] 4208#0: *5 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while 
connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.101, server: vm.demo.com, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "vm.demo.com"
2016/03/14 21:17:04 [crit] 4208#0: *5 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while 
connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.101, server: vm.demo.com, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "vm.demo.com"
2016/03/14 21:18:01 [crit] 4208#0: *5 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while 
connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.101, server: vm.demo.com, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "vm.demo.com"
```

when i check the /tmp/php-fpm.sock file, it's existing

```
[root@vbox1 vhost]# ll /tmp/php-fpm.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 www www 0 Mar 14 21:06 /tmp/php-fpm.sock
```

this are php and nginx running status:

```
[root@vbox1 vhost]# systemctl status php-fpm.service
● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-03-14 21:06:27 CST; 42min ago
  Process: 4189 ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGINT $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4198 (php-fpm)
   CGroup: /system.slice/php-fpm.service
           ├─4198 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─4199 php-fpm: pool www
           └─4200 php-fpm: pool www

Mar 14 21:06:27 vbox1 systemd[1]: Started The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Mar 14 21:06:27 vbox1 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
[root@vbox1 vhost]# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - nginx
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-03-14 21:06:35 CST; 42min ago
  Process: 4180 ExecStop=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s quit (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4206 ExecStart=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4207 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─4207 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
           ├─4208 nginx: worker process
           └─4209 nginx: worker process

Mar 14 21:06:35 vbox1 systemd[1]: Starting nginx...
Mar 14 21:06:35 vbox1 systemd[1]: Started nginx.
```

Can someone help me? If anyone encountered the same problem

Comment: Does `nginx` also run as user `www`?

Comment: @RichardSmith yeah . it is .[root@vbox1 wmq]# ps aux | grep nginx
root      4207  0.0  0.4  47644  2024 ?        Ss   21:06   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
www       6143  0.0  0.3  48036  1968 ?        S    22:00   0:01 nginx: worker process
www       6144  0.0  0.5  48428  2820 ?        S    22:00   0:00 nginx: worker process

Answer (score 10):

I have met the same problem.
And I just change the socket path to another directory but '/tmp',
Then everything goes OK.

Comment: How do you do this? What does it entail?

Comment: @User I am sure something wrong with socket path I haven't used vagrant before but generally on linux the socket path is under `/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock` and what i see also is that he is using `php7.0` so the fpm socket should be something like `php7.0-fpm.sock`

Comment: It works. I have met the same problem with sock under `/tmp/`, the user should have permission to access but got denied. After move to '/var/run/', it works!

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the problem arises with ONE process (php-fpm) setting up the sock in the **/tmp** path, but it would not be visible by ANOTHER process (nginx).

There is a setting in the service config, which would block files created by different process, even though using the same user.

Find your service config file (ex: ***/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service***) and then on add this setting: ***PrivateTmp=No*** to both your services (php and nginx).

```
[Service]
...
PrivateTmp=No
```

more info about systemd units here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found a config (php5) that continues to use the unix socket and does not involve editing any other config files (except the nginx default site file).

```
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
# \Add following to use sqlite as db.
fastcgi_param DB_CONNECTION sqlite;
```

}

Note:- the unix socket is not at `/run/php/` (though it is for php7).
The `include fastcgi_params;` is required to prevent the php file downloading instead of being interpreted.

For completeness the following is my entire default file.

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sponk.co.uk;

  rewrite_log on;

  root /vagrant/public_html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the listen.owner and the listen.group

listen.owner = nginx

listen.group = nginx

In my case in this file: /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

The socket must be the same in you nginx block (like vhost in apache). I also moved the socket under /var/sockets

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing user in `/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to nginx and restart service.

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those who use Homestead inside Vagrant:

I solved simply reloading vagrant with provision flag:
from project root:

```
cd Homestead
```

and then:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

in this manner recompile all configurations

Answer (score -4):

I had this problem, you can do this:

```
chmod 777 yourpath/php-fpm.sock
```

This worked for me.

Comment: avoid chmod 777 for security